# Trying to incorporate members area from one site into another

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a website where I need to use the login form to log into a different site and then bring the member's area from that site over to the one I am building.

I have access to both sites and can make changes on either one. I would incorporate the code from the old one directly but it is in ASP and I'm working with PHP.

Any ideas? The purpose would be for someone to login to the site through site A (no problem) then get the information from site B (no problem) and present it in site A (no problem if I use cURL to get the site and break it up then display it on the new one). The issue I get into is the links that are on the new site and gathered from the old site will still point to links on the old site. Maybe there is a way to dynamically generate those pages on the new site somehow? Or am I going about it all the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's essentially a proxy. You need to parse and rebuild the links in the html source code received from site B. There are no functions available for this, but there are numerous open-source proxy scripts you can take code from.

Glype should be open-source (site appears to be broken now unfortunately).

https://www.glype.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the links to change them depending on where do they point.

1. Links to css/js should be rewritten to point to the real url (note that ajax content won't work, because you can't do an ajax request to another website)
2. Absolute links to the real website should be changed to relative
3. Relative links should point at your website (ex. `$new_url = '/viewpage/?page=' . urlencode($url);`)
4. Absolute links to other domains (not the old website that you proxy) should be dealt somehow, think about what do you want to do with them exactly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try to go with the proxy method by using the Glype project above since I need to be able to pass cookies and a session ID as well.